# JAVA one player version of the game "BattleShip

Tags: java, eclipse

This game uses a 2d array(7x7) and uses two array lists to store the ship (of lengths 2,3,4) and user guesses. The user first types the row and column of each ship and the orientation (either extending down or right). Then a blank board is printed to console and the user will guess row and column. If there is a ship in that spot "hit!" is printed to console, else "miss!" is printed. After each guess, the new state of the board is printed where each hit is a "X" and each miss is a "M". also each guess is added to the guess array list. once the user guesses where each element of the ship is, the game is over and the guess history is printed. My code seems to be working however I am having trouble ending the game. It never gets out of the while loop in the main. Here is my code, is there something that I am doing wrong or need to change?

===========================================================================
My code:

```
class Ship {
int x;
int y;
//String orient;

public Ship (int x, int y) {
    super();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    //this.orient = orient;
}
```

}

```
class Guess {
    int row;
    int col;

    public Guess (int row, int col) {
        super();
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }

}


public class CS125_Project5
{
//create the 2d arrays for the realBoard where the user will add the ships
// and the guessBoard which will update when user makes guesses
/////////what i had at first but kept getting nullpointerexception
//static String realBoard[][];
//static String  guessBoard[][];


//with these i get the thing printed but it says null for all values
static String gameBoard[][] = new String[7][7];
static String  guessBoard[][] = new String[7][7];

//creating the arrayList for both ships and guesses
static ArrayList<Ship> ships = new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayList<Guess> guesses = new ArrayList<>();


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////// Constructor
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public CS125_Project5() {

    //initializing the arrays to have a fixed size of 7x7
    //realBoard = new String[7][7];
    //guessBoard = new String[7][7];
    ships = new ArrayList<>();
    guesses = new ArrayList<>();


    //adding a '-' to each element of the 2d arrays for both boards
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            gameBoard[i][j] = "-"; 
            guessBoard[i][j] = "-";
        }
    }
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////// Method to Print the game maker board
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public static void printGameMakerBoard(){
    System.out.print("r\\c\t");

    //printing the column numbers
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        System.out.print(i+"\t");
    }

    //printing the row numbers
    System.out.println();

    //printing the gameMaker board to show user what the board looks like
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        System.out.print(i+"\t");
        for(int j=0;j<7;j++){
            System.out.print(gameBoard[i][j] +"\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


}

public static void updateBoard(int row, int col, String orient, int length) {



    //if statement to determine orientation of ship
    if (orient.contains("r")) {
        int updateCol;
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            updateCol = j + col;
            gameBoard[row][updateCol] = "S";
        } 

    } else {
        int updateRow;
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            updateRow = row + j;
            gameBoard[updateRow][col] = "S";
        }

    }

    printBoard(gameBoard);


}

public static void printBoard(String[][] board) {
    System.out.print("r\\c"+"\t");

    //printing the column numbers
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        System.out.print(i+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println();

    //printing the row numbers

    // printing the guess board 
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        System.out.print(i+"\t");
        for(int j=0;j<7;j++){
            System.out.print(board[i][j] +"\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

private static void addShip(int x, int y, int length, String orient) {

    gameBoard[x][y] = "S";

    if (length == 2 || length == 3 || length == 4) {
        if (orient.contains("d")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
                Ship ship = new Ship(x, y+i);
                ships.add(ship);
            }
        } else {   //orient.contains("s") 
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                Ship ship = new Ship(x+j, y);
                ships.add(ship);
            }
        }
    }
    //      Ship ship = new Ship(x, y);
    //      ships.add(ship);
}

public void guess(int x, int y) {
    //adding user guesses to ArrayList
    Guess g = new Guess(x , y);
    guesses.add(g);

    //check to see if hit or miss, if hit replace user guess with 'X'
    // else if its a miss replace guess with 'M'
    if (gameBoard[x][y] == "S") {
        guessBoard[x][y] = "X";
        System.out.println("Hit!");

        //now remove the ship from the list
        for(int i = 0; i < ships.size(); i++) {
            Ship ship = ships.get(i);
            if (ship.x== x && ship.y == y){
                ships.remove(i);
                break;
            }

        }
    } else {
        guessBoard[x][y] = "M";
        System.out.println("Miss!");

    }
}

public static boolean gameOver() {
    if(ships.size() == 0) {
        return true;
    } return false;

}

public static void printGuesses() {
    System.out.println("Guess || Row Col");
    System.out.println("=====================");
    for(int i = 0; i < guesses.size(); i++) {
        Guess g = guesses.get(i);
        System.out.println(" " + i + "    || " + g.row + "  " + g.col);
    }
}




////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////// Main 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Your program should always output your name and the project number.
    // DO NOT DELETE OR COMMENT OUT. Replace with relevant info.
    System.out.println("Mason Sarna");
    System.out.println("Project 5");
    System.out.println("");
    // Your code should go below this line
    System.out.println("------------Welcome to BattleShip------------");
    //printGameMakerBoard();

    CS125_Project5 userShip = new CS125_Project5();
    //CS125_Project5.printGameMakerBoard();
    printBoard(guessBoard);
    // create scanner
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //initializing variables
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    String orient = "";
    int length = 0;
    /////////////////////
    // Getting user input for row, col, and orientation of 3 different ships, updates/prints the board after each ship input
    for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter coordinates for ship of length "+ i);
        System.out.println("Starting Row (0-6):");
        row = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Starting column (0-6):");
        col = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("From the starting point, extend down or right? (d/r):");
        orient = sc.next().toLowerCase();
        length = i;  
        //CS125_Project5.updateBoard(row, col, orient, length);
        updateBoard(row,col,orient,length);
        CS125_Project5.addShip(row,col, i, orient);
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("------------Final Game Maker Board------------");
    CS125_Project5.printGameMakerBoard();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();



    System.out.println("------------GAME STARTING NOW------------");
    printBoard(guessBoard);



    while(!gameOver()) { 
        System.out.println("Enter guess in row/col:");
        int r = sc.nextInt();
        int c = sc.nextInt();
        if (guesses.contains(r) && guesses.contains(c)) {
            System.out.println("r\\c = " + r + "\\" + c + " has already been guessed");
        } else {
            userShip.guess(r, c);
            CS125_Project5.printBoard(guessBoard);

        }
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");

    } 



    System.out.println("------------Game Over------------");
    CS125_Project5.printGuesses();


}
```

Comment: A debugger would likely help you figure this out and it’s what we would do to help you as well. The loops exit condition is based on the negative of gameOver. Which means the game will continue whenever the number of ships is not 1. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @JasonArmstrong I just want the game to be over when there is no more ships or elements inside the array list for ships. I tried doing when the size equals zero in the gameOver method

Comment: Size equals zero would be the correct condition to check. If the loop is not terminating then ships isn’t empty. I’d recommend debugging to make sure you’re removing ships ships when you expect them to be.